# Apache Mod-Rewrite: Why is this URL not being filtered

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to prevent iPads from connecting to my server, and only allow iPhones.  What is wrong with this mod_rewrite script that is allowing this?

```
#Prevent non-iPhones from connecting to the server.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*Apple-iPhone2C1.* [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*Apple-iPhone3C1.* [NC]
#RewriteRule () http://www.xyz.com/ [R,NC,L]



#The next line prevents version 4.0
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*801.293.* [NC]

#The next line prevents version 3.13
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*705.18.* [NC]

#The next line prevents version 3.21
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*702.405.* [NC]

#The next line prevents version 3.2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*702.367.* [NC]

#Require iPhones to be 3GS or iPhone 4.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*Apple-iPhone2C1.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*Apple-iPhone3C1.* [NC]
```

The offending device has this for a user agent:

```
 Apple-iPad1C1/803.148
```

Answer (score 2):

The `RewriteCond` conditions are applied by default using a logical **AND**, and you need to use **OR** since you are specifying what versions to block instead of what versions to allow:

```
#The next line prevents version 4.0
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*801.293.* [NC,OR]

#The next line prevents version 3.13
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*705.18.* [NC,OR]

#The next line prevents version 3.21
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*702.405.* [NC,OR]

#The next line prevents version 3.2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*702.367.* [NC,OR]

#Require iPhones to be 3GS or iPhone 4.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*Apple-iPhone2C1.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*Apple-iPhone3C1.* [NC,OR]

RewriteRule .* http://destination.example.com/ [R,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a RewriteRule

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

> Browser Dependent Content Description:
>
> At least for important top-level pages
> it is sometimes necessary to provide
> the optimum of browser dependent
> content, i.e. one has to provide a
> maximum version for the latest
> Netscape variants, a minimum version
> for the Lynx browsers and a average
> feature version for all others.
>
> Solution: We cannot use content
> negotiation because the browsers do
> not provide their type in that form.
> Instead we have to act on the HTTP
> header "User-Agent". The following
> condig does the following: If the HTTP
> header "User-Agent" begins with
> "Mozilla/3", the page foo.html is
> rewritten to foo.NS.html and and the
> rewriting stops. If the browser is
> "Lynx" or "Mozilla" of version 1 or 2
> the URL becomes foo.20.html. All other
> browsers receive page foo.32.html.
> This is done by the following ruleset:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Mozilla/3.*
RewriteRule ^foo\.html$         foo.NS.html          [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Lynx/.*         [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Mozilla/[12].*
RewriteRule ^foo\.html$         foo.20.html          [L]

RewriteRule ^foo\.html$         foo.32.html          [L]
```